# Button hover on a changing background

Tags: html, css, hover

I am making a website for a friend but since I'm still a beginner at this I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm making a simple intro page with his name and an enter button. The enter button has a hover function that when you hover your mouse over it it changes color, meanwhile I have a background div loop that iterates through 5 different backgrounds. My button and its hover function work fine on the first background picture, but once it changes the hover function no longer works until it comes back to that very first picture.

The background changing is a css code I found here on stack while I made everything else.

Here's My [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/9sLqwmdx/2/)  **with what I'm working with**.

Any ideas why the button hover isn't working on all the backgrounds?

**HTML**

```
<body class="intro-body">
    <div id="background-change">
        <div class="background-image image1">
            <h1 class="intro-title">Name Here</h1>
            <p class="intro-button intro-button-hover">Enter</p>
        </div>
        <div class="background-image image2">
            <h1 class="intro-title">Name Here</h1>
            <p class="intro-button intro-button-hover">Enter</p>
        </div>
        <div class="background-image image3">
            <h1 class="intro-title">Name Here</h1>
            <p class="intro-button intro-button-hover">Enter</p>
        </div>
        <div class="background-image image4">
            <h1 class="intro-title">Name Here</h1>
            <p class="intro-button intro-button-hover">Enter</p>
        </div>
        <div class="background-image image5">
            <h1 class="intro-title">Name Here</h1>
            <p class="intro-button intro-button-hover">Enter</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.intro-body {
    text-align: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

.intro-title {
    padding-top: 20vh;
    padding-bottom: 5vh;
    font-size: 650%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}

.intro-button {
    border: solid;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;

}

p.intro-button-hover:hover {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.85;
    padding: 23px 48px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    border: unset;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.background-image {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.image1{
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/1200/1200") no-repeat center fixed;

}

.image2{
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/1200/1300") no-repeat center fixed;
}

.image3{
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/1300/1200") no-repeat center fixed;
}

.image4{
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/1300/1300") no-repeat center fixed;
}

.image5{
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/1300/1400") no-repeat center fixed;
}

@keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
#background-change div:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: 20s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
}
#background-change div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: 15s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
}
#background-change div:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}
#background-change div:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}

#background-change div:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

#background-change div {
animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 25s;

-webkit-animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-duration: 25s;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update with the following code, I have just added internal js.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").mouseover(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color", "white");
});
$("p").mouseout(function(){
    $("p").css("background-color", "");
    $("p").css("color", "black");
});
```

});

And remove the properties with '//' in the css:

```
p.intro-button-hover:hover {
// background-color: #fff;
//opacity: 0.4;
padding: 23px 48px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
//color: black;
border: unset;
cursor: pointer;
```

}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9sLqwmdx/10/ It does the same effect as the one I had, only the first one gets the hover

Comment: I don't think so, its working fine for me in the fiddle, just recheck and close the script tag which I forgot to do.

Comment: Hmm, you clicked on the one I linked with your edit? It has the script closed and all

Comment: No wait I see, I had it added on the javascript console while yours is on the html one!

Comment: Yup,just add the script in the head tag... it'll work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly looking at this, the reason for it is that you actually have 5 different buttons fading in and out, which messes things up.

Do something like this (pseudocode)

```
<body class="intro-body">
  <div id="callout">
    <h1 class="intro-title">Name Here</h1>
    <button class="intro-button intro-button-hover">Enter</button>
  </div>
  <div id="background-change">
    <div class="background-image image1"></div>
    <div class="background-image image2"></div>
    <div class="background-image image3"></div>
    <div class="background-image image4"></div>
    <div class="background-image image5"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Naturally position the callout section over the background image and you're good to go.

Comment: Hmm I'm trying a position absolute on callout and a position relative to background-image but it just comes up with the title and button but no background

Comment: My div backgrounds use a postion absolute css, so if I change any of that it messes with the background

Comment: Yes but my images won't cycle unless their div is set to position absolute :/

Comment: I won't code it until the end, but just position absolute your bg images within the containing elements and you're good to go.

Comment: thanks for the help man but I'm not just getting it, if I move any of the image properties to another containing element the background images stop showing

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your code and tried debugging the problem. The problem is mostly from your **animation** code. Try rewriting your animation code. I have tested it removing the animation code, to check if the hover is working properly or not, and it works fine. There is also a bug with your animation code which makes the **Enter** button disappear for a while after the first animation iteration and appear again after few seconds.

If possible try using **JQuery**, as it makes your job easier for using animations. For example, can simply use `fadeIn();` and `fadeOut();` functions for the animation you have been doing in your CSS animation code.